# Analytical Solution of Sound Wave Propagation in Moving Medium (1D Problem)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, flow, doppler-effect

I am trying to use frequency-wavenumber analysis to estimate sound wave propagation in a moving medium (fluid). I need to test the technique on analytical data. I wonder if there is an analytical solution that describes pressure field during sound wave propagation from a point source in a flowing fluid. I expect the pressure field to be a functin of space and time and it should show Doppler shift effect. I am assuming a simple problem with the following assumptions:

- Fluid flow is one-dimensional.
- Fluid motion is uniform.
- Fluid is extending to infinity in both sides (i.e., boundary effects are negligible).
- Sound source is a point-source (i.e., sound source does not affect fluid flow).

I am looking for 1D solution that can estimate acousic wave amplitude as function of space ($x$) and time ($t$). I think the solution should be identical to point source which is moving in a static fluid.

Comment: See Problem 1, page 266, Chapter 68, Landau-Lifshitz, Fluid Mechanics, Vol 6.

Comment: @Navid Thanks for your help. I think this not what I am looking for. I am looking for a solution of pressure wave from a point source in a moving medium. Pressure fluctuation is expected to be function of postion and time. It should clarifies Doppler shift effect.